# PHP/MySQL - Ordering a database table by year and month separately.

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a HTML table from a list of newsletters in a MySQL database.

It's currently ordered by descending order, and outputting as below:

https://jsfiddle.net/e8zrLjqu/

As you will see the years are in the right place, but the months of the newsletters need to be in ascending order, while keeping the years in descending order, so that each newsletter matches up with the table heading....like this example:

Do I somehow need to use DATE_FORMAT to separate the ordering? The date in the database is formatted like this: 2014-07-01

Php:

```
        $category_data_fields = '`id`';
        $category_where_conditions = '`publish` = \'y\' and `fund_id` = ' . $this_fund_id . ' and `category_status` = \'n\'';
        $category_result = $db->selectByStrings($category_data_fields, '`category`', $category_where_conditions, '`position`');
        $resource_data_fields = '`id`, `date`, `heading`, `file`';
        $heading_investor_newsletter = $lang_row['name'] . ' Investor Newsletters';
        $copy_investor_newsletter = $tab0 . $lang_row['investor_news_copy'] . $retn . $retn;
        $note = $tab1 . $lang_row['investor_news_note'] . $retn . $retn;
        if ($db->getNumRows($category_result) > 0)  {
            $cat_data = $db->getNextRow($category_result);
            /*
             * list selectable years
             */

            $resource_where_conditions = '`publish` = \'y\' and `category_id` = ' . $cat_data['id'];
            $date_result = $db->selectByStrings($resource_data_fields, '`resource`', $resource_where_conditions, '`date` desc');
            $current_year = '';
            $base_url_query = (_USE_SEO_URLS === true) ? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&';
            if ($req->isRequest ('year')) $url_year = $req->getRequest ('year');
            if ($db->getNumRows($date_result) > 0)  {
                $copy_investor_newsletter .= $tab0 . '<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive"><tbody><thead><tr><th>January</th><th>Feburay</th><th>March</th><th>April</th><th>May</th><th>June</th><th>July</th><th>August</th><th>September</th><th>October</th><th>November</th><th>December</th></tr></thead>' . $retn;
                while ($data = $db->getNextRow($date_result))   {
                    if (substr ($data['date'], 0, 4) != $current_year)  {
                        $current_year = substr ($data['date'], 0, 4);
                        if (!isset ($latest_year)) $latest_year = $current_year;
                        if (!isset ($url_year)) {
                            $navsel = ' class="ActNav"';
                            $url_year = $current_year;
                        } elseif ($url_year == $current_year)   {
                            $navsel = ' class="ActNav"';
                            $selected_year = $url_year;
                        } else $navsel = '';
                        $copy_investor_newsletter .= $tab1 . '<tr>';
                //      if ($url_year == $current_year) {
                            /*
                             * read and display all newsletters for selected year
                             */
                            $resource_where_conditions = '`publish` = \'y\' and `category_id` = ' . $cat_data['id'] . ' and substr(`date`,1,4) = \'' . $current_year . '\'';
                            $resource_result = $db->selectByStrings($resource_data_fields, '`resource`', $resource_where_conditions, '`date` desc');
                            if ($db->getNumRows($resource_result) > 0)  {
                        //      $copy_investor_newsletter .= $retn . $tab2 . '<ul>' . $retn;
                                while ($data = $db->getNextRow($resource_result))   {
                                    $copy_investor_newsletter .= $tab3 . '<td><a href="#" target="_blank">' . $data['heading'] . '</a></td>' . $retn;
                                }
                            //  $copy_investor_newsletter .= $tab2 . '</ul>' . $retn . $tab1;
                            }
            //          }
                        $copy_investor_newsletter .= '</tr>' . $retn;
                    }
                }
                $copy_investor_newsletter .= $tab0 . '</tbody></table>' . $retn . $retn;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
... ORDER BY YEAR(`date`) DESC, MONTH(`date`) ASC
```

See also the documentation of [YEAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [MONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: There isn't a year column in the database, I'm assuming it would need one for this to work? I only have a date column available and thought maybe I could use DATE_FORMAT somehow to order it just from that column alone?

Comment: `YEAR` is a MySQL function that extracts the year from the `date` column. `MONTH` will extract the month from `date` column. Please try out the code snippet of my answer.

Comment: Ok thank you I see, I did try it but it didn't have any effect on the ordering I'm afraid

Comment: Did you replace `\`date\` desc` by `YEAR(\`date\`) DESC, MONTH(\`date\`) ASC` in your PHP code?

Comment: `$date_result = $db->selectByStrings($resource_data_fields, '\`resource\`', $resource_where_conditions, 'YEAR(\`date\`) DESC, MONTH(\`date\`) ASC');`

Comment: Yes, I've double checked it, still ordering it the same way.